# Mulitple row insert into db in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

ajax change function execute `listByBatch()` and show the table with data by batch which is post by ajax. And then I trying to insert table rows by `insertAttendance`, code below:

```
 Jquery post:

    $("#batch-list").change(function(){
                /*dropdown post */
                $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/attendance/list_ByBatch",    
                data: {batchid: $(this).val()},
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data){ 
                    $("#traineeList").html(data);
                    $("#subTotal").html("Total: " + $('#traineeList tr').length.toString());
                    document.getElementById("classHour").defaultValue = "4";
                }
                });
             });

Controller:

    public function list_ByBatch() {
        $batch = $this->input->post('batchid', TRUE);
        $data['trainee']= $this->AttendanceModel->get_traineeList($batch);
        if (!empty($data['trainee'])) {
            echo form_open('attendance/insertAttendance');
                echo"<table class='table table-hover type-list2'id='traineeList'>
                    <tr class='success'>
                        <th>Trainee ID</th>
                        <th>Trainee Name</th>
                        <th>Present</th>
                    </tr>";
                foreach ($data['trainee'] as $row) {
                    echo "
                    <tr><td>" . str_pad($row->TraineeID, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row->Name . "</td>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' name='.$row->TraineeID[]' value='" . $row->TraineeID . "' checked></td>
                    </tr>";
                }
                echo"</table>";
                echo"
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='form-group col-sm-2'>
                        <h5 id='subTotal'></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group col-sm-6'>
                        <input type='date' class='form-control' name='attnDate' id='attnDate' placeholder='Attendance Date' required>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group col-sm-2'>
                        <input type='number ' class='form-control' name='classHour' id='classHour' placeholder='Class Hour' required>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group col-sm-2'>
                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-success' name='record' value='Record'>
                    </div>
                </div>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
    }

    public function insertAttendance() {
        $TID ['TID']= $this->input->post('trainee');
        $attnDate = $this->input->post('attnDate');
        $classHour = $this->input->post('classHour');
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($TID);

        if(is_array($TID)){
            foreach ($TID as $TID=>$key) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_attn_temp` (TraineeID, Date, classHour) VALUES ('" . $key . "','" . $attnDate . "','" . $classHour . "')";
                $this->db->query($query);
            }
        }else{
            echo "Trainee ID is not array";
        }

    }
```

I just trying to insert all rows (TraineeID) shows in table with "attnDate" and 'classHour" by clicking submit button.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You want to know how to dynamically update the view?

Comment: Yes, my ajax change function post "batchid" and with this "batchid" I get the list in controller " $data['trainee'] ". I just need to pass " $data['trainee'] " to view with this change function that I can print this array in my view page.

Comment: Added this line but it does not get in view page. anything I need to do in view page or in ajax?

Comment: You cannot pass a variable returned by an ajax call to a view that is already loaded and have it use the new data. I see two ways to update the screen. First, you can reload the whole view passing `$data['trainee']` to the controller which will pass it to the view . Second, in `list_ByBatch()` you rebuild the table row's html. Return that html to `success:`. Then the line `$("#traineeList").html(data);` will do the trick.

Comment: @DFriend, yes I can make it the second way, and I tried that all view code in controller and print with the variable, getting fine. But in this case, I cannot submit the form to insert all table rows into database. Could you help me to do this, if I will go with the second way.

Comment: Show me your code for "the second way" of doing `list_ByBatch()`. (Edit your original question to add this information.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93203/discussion-between-mir-abzal-ali-and-dfriend).

Comment: still I could not received this "<td><input type='checkbox' name='.$row->TraineeID[]' value='" . $row->TraineeID . "' checked></td>" value by post, please anybody help me, that how do I receive this value to insert db.